# Can I limit folder rename, copy, move, delete operations using SFGAO flags?

Tags: filesystems, windows-shell, shell-namespace-extension, windows-shell-extension-menu

I need to limit certain operations with folder in Windows Explorer. For example disallow copy, move, rename, delete operations or make it read-only (disallow creation of new files and folders in it).

I see that there are [SFGAO flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/sfgao) that looks what I need: SFGAO_CANCOPY, SFGAO_CANMOVE, SFGAO_CANRENAME, SFGAO_CANDELETE, SFGAO_READONLY. However they require shell namespace extension to be created. Can I somehow set these attributes on real folders in file system without creating a full blown namespace extension? For example by creating some registry settings for the specific folder?

Comment: The only things you can customize for a file system folder at Shell level are related to UI/Presentation. What would it mean to disallow actions that any API and/or other applications (cmd.exe, etc.) can still run?

Answer (score 1):

The SFGAO flags are determined by the `IShellFolder` implementation.

3rd-party verbs can be controlled by setting [the `AttributeMask` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-use-item-attributes).

A [custom folder instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms997573.aspx) lets you control the flags of the folder but not its contents.

In a standard file-system folder I believe the read-only attribute just comes from the normal "DOS" file attribute. There is no way to control the rename/delete/properties flags.